# About a small child doing zina

Tags: zina, children

I know a small boy doing zina because of being oppressed and beaten up.He is a poor one.I feel sorry for him I need to help him.
What is the punishment for zina for small children and how should it be dealt with in light of islamic teachings?
Requesting answer from someone with knowledge.

The small child crossdressed and masterbates. He is like ten years old. He was bullied and doesn't have a supportive background. He was finding ways of suicide. Please give us an Islamic punishment and teaching to support

Comment: please have sympathy and dont vote negative just because its a zina question.I love the child so much.

Comment: How can a small child commit zina? This hardly makes sense. Elaborate and explain yourself, what you've posted is simply weird.

Comment: Its urtuba,
Please add this in comments,
The small child crossdressed and masterbates. He is like ten years old. He was bullied and doesn't have a supportive background. He was finding ways of suicide. Please give us an Islamic punishment and teaching to support.

Comment: Masturbation and zina are two different things one is punishable (in this life) the other not, so why are you speaking of zina, when there's no act of zina here.

Comment: You might want to look at [this post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46103/38359). As you put it, the child seems to be the victim of the situation and regardless of his actions has the right to protection. His physical and mental well-being should be the main concern.